# How to remove nonalphanumeric character in python but keep some special characters

Tags: python, regex

I figure out how to remove special non alphanumeric character in python using the following function:

```
p_nonalphanum = re.compile('\W+')

def removeNonAlphaNum(string):
        m = p_nonalphanum.match(string)
        if m:
            string = string[m.end():]
        return string
```

I would like to keep some specials characters though such as ½, ¾ which i consider as number. How should i edit my regex?

> **e.g: from** "• ½ cup flour" **to** "½ cup flour"

Comment: Are you sure this is working for you so far? `>>> removeNonAlphaNum('-hello-')`
`'hello-'`

Comment: Only non alpha num characters starting in a string matters to me but this could be extended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def remove_unwanted(s):
...     '''• ½ cup flour -> ½ cup flour'''
...     allowed = '[\w½¾]+'
...     return ' '.join(re.findall(allowed, s))
... 
>>> print remove_unwanted('• ½ cup flour ->')
½ cup flour
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negated character class and add all characters you want to keep

You could do something like this:

```
p_nonalphanum = re.compile('[^\w½¾]+')
print (p_nonalphanum.sub('', test))
```

Comment: this sounds like the first good solution as i want to edit my regex but I have this error message: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file

Comment: ok i just need to add this first line in my python script: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with a regex where you manually add each character you want, use the builtin `isalnum` function!

```
>>> s = "• ½ cup flour -> ½ cup flour"
>>> def only_alphanum(s):
...     s = unicode(s, "utf-8")
...     return ' '.join(c for c in s.split() if c.isalnum())
... 
>>> print only_alphanum(s)
½ cup flour ½ cup flour
```

This will let you catch any fraction, instead of just the list of fractions that you've assembled in your regex(which could get long very quickly)

```
>>> s = "• ¼ cup oats -*(*&!!"
>>> print only_alphanum(s)
¼ cup oats
```